# In Linux(RedHat) , C function malloc_stats() shows different values compared to /proc/<pid>/stat resident memory size

Tags: c, linux, malloc, redhat, glibc

e.g.
For a process running in Redhat linux
as per /proc/{pid}/stat's resident pages * page size => 30 GB

as per [malloc_stats()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html) => 2.5 GB

any idea why this happens ?

```
Arena 0:
system bytes     =  465162240
in use bytes     =  465037200
Arena 1:
system bytes     =    1003520
in use bytes     =     980656
Arena 2:
system bytes     =    8065024
in use bytes     =    7771728
Arena 3:
system bytes     = 2278395904
in use bytes     = 2276584320
Arena 4:
system bytes     =    1482752
in use bytes     =    1236112
Arena 5:
system bytes     =    1482752
in use bytes     =    1235440
Arena 6:
system bytes     =    1482752
in use bytes     =    1240512
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     = 2782,699,520
in use bytes     = 2779710544
max mmap regions =          9
max mmap bytes   =   25624576
```

Answer (score 3):

`malloc_stats` is tied to the implementation of `malloc` in user-land.

`pmap` or `/proc/self/stat`  is related to the virtual address space and its perception in kernel land, which changes not only with `mmap` called by `malloc` but also with other calls to `mmap`, including those related to the dynamic linker (`ld.so`)

Read a good [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). See also https://linuxatemyram.com/ and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)